# python background process

Tags: python, python-2.7, multiprocessing

I'm trying to write a process in Python which runs indefinitely and spawns exactly "n" number of processes in background which run some python code. I do not care for the output/result of these background processes, but would like to know when any of them terminate so that I always have "n" processes running. Any ideas how I can go about this or some reference material that could help?

Thanks & Regards,
Azeem

Comment: go checking `multiprocessing` module

Answer (score 3):

I would use a [multiprocessing.Pool](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.pool) for this type of work. You can create a pool with a given number of worker processes and assign python functions to them to be run.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import time

def f(x):
    print(x)
    time.sleep(1)
    print("finished", x)

pool = Pool(processes=4)

for x in xrange(10):
    pool.apply_async(f, [x])

pool.close()

pool.join()
```

Returns the following:

```
0
1
2
3
('finished', 0)
('finished', 1)
('finished', 2)
('finished', 3)
4
5
6
7
('finished', 5)
('finished', 7)
('finished', 4)
('finished', 6)
8
9
('finished', 8)
('finished', 9)
```